# popstate does not work since safari 16? It was working until safari 15

Tags: javascript, safari, popstate

I would like to display an image when the user clicks the back button of the browser.
The code below worked fine in safari 15.5, but when I upgraded to safari 16.1, it did not work.
Popstate not working in safari 16.1?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
      history.replaceState(null, null, null)
      history.pushState(null, null, null);
      window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
        alert('fired');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>test</body>
</html>
```

I confirmed that when I clicked the browser back button in safari 15, the alert message was displayed.
When I ran it in safari 16, nothing was executed and the previous page was displayed as is.

Comment: I've found that if you long-press on the back button in Safari and choose the first entry from the list, it works as it used to for previous versions (Safari 15 & 14).

Comment: See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=248303 (no response from the WebKit team on that yet)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had some async scripts in HTML and some browser abilities were blocked until those scripts loaded completely.